# How to clear the typeahead input after a result is selected?

Tags: typeahead, ng-bootstrap

I'm using the [ng-bootstrap typeahead](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/typeahead) component to search a customer database. When the user selects a customer from the typeahead results list, I navigate to a customer details page. I've got this working, but I want to clear the input field after navigation has taken place. I've tried setting the model to null or an empty string in the `selectItem` event logic, but this isn't working:

**customer-search-typeahead.component.html**

```
<template #resultTemplate let-r="result" let-t="term">
  <div>
    <div>
      {{r.resource.name[0].given}} {{r.resource.name[0].family}}
    </div>
    <div>
      {{r.resource.birthDate | date: 'dd/MM/yyyy'}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<input type="text" class="form-control" [resultTemplate]="resultTemplate" (selectItem)="onSelect($event)"
       [(ngModel)]="model" placeholder="Start typing a customer name..." [ngbTypeahead]="search"/>
```

**customer-search-typeahead.component.ts**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'customer-search-typeahead',
  template: require('./customer-search-typeahead.component.html'),
  styles: [`.form-control { width: 300px; }`]
})
export class CustomerSearchTypeaheadComponent {

  model: any;
  searching: boolean;

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService, private router: Router) {}

  onSelect($event) {
    this.router.navigate(['/customers', $event.item.resource.id]);
    this.model = null;
  };

  search = (text$: Observable<string>) =>
   //omitted for brevity
}
```

The typeahead input looks like this after a selection has been made:

[image]

---

**Solution**

**customer-search-typeahead.component.html**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" #input [ngbTypeahead]="search" (selectItem)="onSelect($event); input.value='' ">
```

**customer-search-typeahead.component.ts**

```
onSelect($event, input) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    this.router.navigate(['/customers', $event.item.resource.id]);
  };
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The issue you witnessing arises from the fact that the `NgModel` directive is updating model binding asynchronously and the actual model is updated *after* the `onSelect` method gets executed. So your model update gets overridden by the `NgModel` functionality.

Fortunately we (ng-bootstrap authors) got all the flex points in place to cover your use-case :-) There are a couple of things that you could do.

Firstly the `$event` object passed to the `onSelect` method has the `preventDefault()` method and you can call it to veto item selection (and as a result writing back to the model and input field update).

`$event.preventDefault()` will make sure that the model is not updated and the input field is not updated with the selected item. But text entered by a user will still be part of the input so if you want to clear up this as well you can directly update the `input`'s `value` property.

Here is code demonstrating all those techniques together:

```
onSelect($event, input) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    this.selected.push($event.item);
    input.value = '';
  }
```

where `input` argument is a reference to the input DOM element:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" #input 
   [ngbTypeahead]="search" (selectItem)="onSelect($event, input)">
```

Finally here is a plunker showing all this in practice: http://plnkr.co/edit/kD5AmZyYEhJO0QQISgbM?p=preview

Comment: I've just noticed that this works for the first search and the input box is cleared, but subsequent searches result in the search string remaining in the input field. I've tried all the combinations you've suggested.

Comment: @BlakeMumford I see! I've updated my answer based on your use-case and comments. Hope it covers your needs right now.

Comment: Hi, that works well, but then my component is performing DOM manipulation. I have updated my question with the solution I eventually went with. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @BlakeMumford you can always go through the `Renderer` abstraction if you are worried about direct DOM manipulation: `this._renderer.setElementProperty(input, 'value', '');`. Updated plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/n3G2kEp7sZFNy0cGOSxv?p=preview

Comment: As `Renderer` is deprecated, you should use `Renderer2`. So, firstly import it 
`import { Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';`, then inject 
`constructor(private renderer: Renderer2) {}` and use like this in your `selectItem($event, input: HTMLInputElement)` method: `this.renderer.setProperty(input, 'value', '');`

Answer (score 1):

The above one is template ref value solution.

This is for ngModel solution.

Html code:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [resultTemplate]="resultTemplate" (selectItem)="onSelect($event)"
       [(ngModel)]="model" placeholder="Start typing a customer name..." [ngbTypeahead]="search"/>
```

Component code:

```
onSelect($event) {
    $event.preventDefault();
    this.model = null;
    this.router.navigate(['/customers', $event.item.resource.id]);
};
```

> $event.preventDefault();

for ngModel value change empty